# Why doesn't this TCP connection in python doesnt work?

Tags: python, tcp, network-programming

im trying to create a program that can do Command Line commands on my other pc over an TCP python server... but when i want to get the result of my command its just stuck there does nothing and staring at me... help will be appreciated

Client:

```
try:
    sock.sendall("3")
    if sock.recv(10000) == "ready for sandbox":
        print "ready to transmit"   
except:
    print "error"
    sys.exit(1)

while True:
    try:
        command = raw_input("--> ")
        sock.sendall(command)
        sock.recv(10000)
    except:
        print "connection lost"
        sys.exit(1)
```

Server:

```
while True:
        data = connection.recv(10000)
        print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data

    elif data == "3":
        connection.sendall("ready for sandbox")
        while True:
                try:
                    cmd_data = connection.recv(10000)
                    os.system(cmd_data +" > C:\output.txt")
                    result = open(r"C:\output.txt",'r').readlines()
                    connection.sendall(result)
                except:
                    pass
```

I want to be able as the client always send commands and receive their outputs... and the Server should be error free as possible or atleast not to crash

By the way.. the indentations in my programs are ok if you find indentation mistakes it's probably because of stackoverflow...

Server cmd:

```
starting up on localhost port 10000
waiting for connection
connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52674)
received "3"
```

Client cmd:

```
--> 3
connecting to localhost port 10000
ready to transmit
--> dir
```

Help? :(

Comment: You might be having trouble `recv()`ing 10000 bytes if you didn't `sendall()` that many.

Comment: for this basic socket example, here is a nice example on the Python page. https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example

Comment: Err.. I didn't get it..:/

Comment: Thanks every one.. but my friend checked up my code and assisted me..

Comment: Please tell us what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that it tried to send loop instead of string so fixing the loop and `str(result)` did the job pretty much.... works flawlessly now